# useCallback context not receiving updated value after context is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

When I call getRequestContext anywhere in my app after I have updated context, my callback does not use the new value, but instead always uses the old value. Any ideas on how to ensure that I always retrieve the most up to date context value when getRequestContext is called?

```
export function useData() {
  const context = useContext(dataStateContext);

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useData must be used within a dataProvider");
  }

  const getRequestContext = useCallback(async () => {

    const requestContext = {
      headers: context.headers,
      env: context.env,
      id: context.id ?? ""    
    };
    return requestContext;
  }, [context]);

  return {
    getRequestContext,
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you updating the context value within the context provider?

Comment: I am, and I have confirmed that that value gets updated correctly, and context is updated right above `getRequestContext`. However inside of the callback the value is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a ref, below is the updated code.

```
export function useData() {
  const context = useContext(dataStateContext);

  const contextValueRef = useRef(context);
  useEffect(() => {
    contextValueRef.current = context;
  }, [context]);

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useData must be used within a dataProvider");
  }

  const getRequestContext = useCallback(async () => {
    const updatedContext = contextValueRef.current || context;
    const requestContext = {
      headers: updatedContext.headers,
      env: updatedContext.env,
      id: updatedContext.id ?? ""    
    };
    return requestContext;
  }, [context]);

  return {
    getRequestContext,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useEffect()` hook to trigger the re-renders when the context change happens,

```
const [contextState, setContextState] = useState(context);

  useEffect(() => {
    setContextState(context);
  }, [context]);

  const getRequestContext = useCallback(async () => {
    const requestContext = {
      headers: contextState.headers,
      env: contextState.env,
      id: contextState.id ?? ""    
    };
    return requestContext;
  }, [contextState]);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. contextState will still be outdated inside of `getRequestContext`